# Twilio will not send vCard with a photo included

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, twilio, vcf-vcard

I am creating my vCard with the vObjects module using the following:

```
def _create_vcard(assigned_address, write_to_disk=False):
    vCard = vobject.vCard()
    vCard.add('N').value = vobject.vcard.Name(given='EXAMPLE')
    vCard.add('FN').value = "EXAMPLE"

    vCard.add('EMAIL')
    vCard.email.value = 'info@EX.com'
    vCard.email.type_param = 'SUPPORT_EMAIL'

    vCard.add('TEL')
    vCard.tel.value = assigned_address
    vCard.tel.type_param = 'SYSTEM_NUMBER'

    vCard.add('URL')
    vCard.url.value = 'https://X.com/'
    vCard.url.type_param = 'WEBSITE'

    vCard.add('PHOTO;ENCODING=b;TYPE=image/jpeg').value = _b64_image('assets/example.jpg') # This line

    vCard_data = vCard.serialize()
```

Then sending the serialized data to a public S3 bucket

```
def _write_vcard_to_s3_bucket(vCard_data, number):
    file_name = number[1:-1] + ".vcf"

    client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = client.put_object( 
        Bucket='EX-vcards',
        Body=vCard_data,
        Key=file_name,
        ContentType='text/x-vcard'
    )

    bucket_url = f'https://EX.s3.amazonaws.com/{file_name}'
    return bucket_url
```

Twilio Code

```
def twilio_send_test_message(number, vcard_url):
    client = get_twilio_client()
    message = client.messages.create(
         body=f'example message with vCard',
         from_= number,
         media_url=[vcard_url],
         to='+1USPHONENUMBER'
    )
    return message
```

_b64 function

```
def _b64_image(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        b64 = base64.b64encode(f.read())

    final = b64.decode('utf-8')
    return final
```

When commenting the photo line out out, the vCard sends just fine, but with it, it does not work.

I have also texted it by writing it out to a .vcf locally, and it works fine with the image if saved locally.

Am I doing something clearly wrong?

Comment: Very confused here. You mention it doesn't send with Twilio but your sample code doesn't show any Twilio sending code nor an error message (or does it not save on S3?). When I try your code I can save vCard's on S3 with and without images and they look formatted correctly. Please also share the `_b64_image` function so we can see that you correctly create the image data.

Comment: @Yvesonline, my error, I though I grabbed it all.

I added the twiliio code and the _b64 code

Comment: OK but you say `it does not work`, what doesn't work? The Twilio sending? What error message are you getting? Does the API request not go through or is the vCard not being displayed properly?

Comment: When sending without the photo, it works fine, the attached contact is openable and looks great. When using the photo, the file either does not send with the message, or the file is unopenable.